# Non-photorealistic shading + outline in an illustration aesthetic style

Tags: rendering, materials, shaders, freestyle, npr

I am working on a project, and I want to replicate the Charles Schulz-esque line style and grain-flavoured airbrush shading. How do I do this in the attached figures in Blender?

[image: illustrated figures showing materials]

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

### Textured self shadow

On Eevee, you can achieve that by converting a Diffuse shader into RGB data via the `Shader to RGB` node, then tweak that a little bit to use is as a mask for two colors/textures:

[image: shader setup]

The Color Ramp changes the limits of the shadow, the Color Burn adds the noise, and then you can use that as a factor for either a mix RGB or a mix Shader.

### Flat cast shadow

The edge blurring of shadows is mainly tied to the size parameter of your light objects:

[image: light size]

As for its color, it is partially influenced in Eevee by the ambient light or your scene, aka the World Shader color:

[image: world shader]

You can change it if you want, using a `Shader to RGB` node:

[image: flat shadow shader]

### Lines

There are multiple ways to make lines.

#### Freestyle

It's a post process render engine that is applied on top of a render made from Eevee or Cycles. Hence, you can't see it from the viewport and have to run a render.
You can enable it in the Properties Editor > Render settings tab > Freestyle panel.

Then most of the settings of how Freestyle behaves is located in the View Layer tab:

[image: Freestyle Settings]

#### Grease Pencil

As explained by @common_goldfish, you can use the lineart system, which under the hood adds an object with a LineArt modifier from the Grease Pencil drawing system. You can add a linerat on a per-object basis, or even on a collection. I.E. you can make a collection `Contour` with all the object you want to draw a contour line for, and then press <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> Grease Pencil > Collection Line Art.

[image: line art]

This one is visible from the viewport, so it is easier to setup because you can see what it does without having to run a render. But it is drawn from the camera, so turning your viewport around from outside of the render camera will look a bit weird:

[image: weird]

#### Inverted duplicated mesh

The oldest trick when it comes to faking contour in 3D is to make a copy of your mesh, inflate it a bit to the outside, disable the backface rendering and set the diplaced mesh's material to your contour color.

For the duplication and inflation, you can do it manually in edit mode via <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> then <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>. Another simple way to do that in Blender is via the solidify modifier:

[image: Duplicate mesh setup]

This method has the advantage of letting you edit the thickness right from the duplicate mesh itself.

Comment: Looks pretty by the way in this case! But I also need answers for that line style and flat shadow where it can blend with the shaders (car window, etc.)

Comment: Oh yeah I missed quite some tuff. I edited my answer, let me know how it goes for you.

Answer (score 1):

A way to create line art:

Select an object and make your camera view active.
You can get the line style by using by `shift+a` to add a new object, then go to `grease pencil` choose `object line art`.  This will create a line art modifier, when selected you can adjust line thickness.[image]

[image]

[image]