How can I create Benday dots/Halftones for my 2D Blender Animation
So i am new to 2D animation in blender, and for my project i needed to create a pop art animation, but unfortunately i couldn't find texture brush or anything related/ to create a benday dots or Halftone effect for the animation, so is there anyother way to make it happpen in 2d.
A brush/texture pack or anything

It would help if you posted some images of either an example from a 3rd party that you're aiming for or your current project that you need help with, or both. It's not easy to answer if you just say you want "benday dots" and not much else. Does it need to be a shader? Part of the UVd models texture? Post-Process effect in screenspace?

A couple posts for you to consider:
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102352/blender-halftone-pattern-filter

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/296853/how-do-i-create-dot-texture-to-use-for-halftone-in-blenders-compositor

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/278596/non-photorealistic-shading-outline-in-an-illustration-aesthetic-style/278597#278597

I really do appericate your help, but im not doing my project in 3d. And i figured out that its not actually that hard to create half tone pattern in blender, i can do them manually. Basically im doing my project in an 80's pop art style so I needed those halftone/benday pattern for style purpose. but I can do them manually too. Again thanks for your help
